# Where is alsa-base.conf located in Debian 10?

Tags: linux, debian, alsa

So....I need to add some configuration (`options snd-hda-intel model=`) to the `alsa-base.conf` as I did in my previous installation of Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, it seems like I have no `alsa-base.conf` file (or at least not in the same location as in ubuntu `/etc/modprobe.d`).

Where should I add my options when using Debian 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alsa-base.conf` is no longer available in Debian 10.

That doesn’t mean you can’t set your HDA options; those can go in any file with a name ending in `.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d`, ideally a file of your own. I use `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf` to store all my module options.

Comment: Jesus, I was reading through so much documentation and no reference to this....and so it seems that either I am the only one that di not find this info or other people do not have any issues with that requires that, because there are absolutely no reference :D fuck my life two days for nothing. Just so I will not need to ask another question. When I did in ubuntu I made a personal pin configuration file in /lib/firmware/personal.fw and in options added patch=personal.fw will this way of doing still work? I don't have enough rep to upvote :(

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t have any idea off-hand regarding your `personal.fw` file; please do ask another question ;-).

Comment: I will first try to see if it works, and otherwise ask a question, not to spam unnecessarily. Thank you a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have found with many distributions that folder /etc/modprobe.d is empty
but user can add .conf files if required

i use this on many systems to stop error beeps:

```
echo 'blacklist pcspkr' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/nobeep.conf
```

to create the file you need:

```
echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=xxxxxx' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

replace 'xxxxxx' with model name

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. I've been going nuts as to why all my usb audio devices were no longer seen and this gave me the idea. Created my own .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d containing just
options snd-usb-audio index=0,1
options snd-hda-intel index=2,3
and lo and behold all audio devices were in play again.